What is the difference between giving, e.g., :test 'eq and :test #'eq as arguments to make-hash-table?
Like many functions handling collections of elements, make-hash-table accepts a :test option. The docstring states that TEST must be a symbol, and that 'eq, 'eql and 'equal have predefined meaning.
When looking at all the elisp source code found in directories listed in the load-path, I find ≈ 150 instances where make-hash-table is called with :test 'some_symbol and
≈ 150 instances with :test #'some_function_name (so, not a symbol!). Thus, by my reading of the docstring, half of the uses of make-hash-table :test ... in the Lisp sources in Emacs do not respect the spec. But obviously the resulting code still works perfectly fine.
My question is: is there any difference between giving, e.g., :test 'eq and :test #'eq as arguments to make-hash-table? The question can be asked in two contexts: one where eq has not been modified by the user, and one where eq as been redefined.

When you get an answer, consider filing an Emacs bug (M-x report-emacs-bug). Sounds like the doc doesn't always correspond to what's true in practice.

The doc string says :test has to be a symbol. But the Elisp manual doesn't say that.

Interestingly, the Elisp manual for define-hash-table-test describes what's needed for make-hash-table as a "name" (argument NAME). You give define-hash-table-test a NAME arg and functions as the other args, and then you can pass NAME to make-hash-table. Not too clear: Is NAME a string? string or symbol? Is the value of NAME really what you pass to make-hash-table? Actually, NAME` must be a symbol, because the manual talks about its property list.

"... (so, not a symbol!)." - you are jumping to an unwarranted conclusion here. Try evaluating (symbolp #'some_function_name).

Thanks a lot to you all. I just realized, after 35+ years of using Emacs Lisp, that #'foo does not mean (symbol-function 'foo) as I somehow believed without ever thinking about it very precisely. A small epiphany but one nevertheless...

'eq and #'eq both satisfy symbolp, but the latter informs the byte-compiler that you're talking specifically about a function, which can sometimes result in better code being generated. See function in the emacs-lisp manual.

The #'foo notation is what is known as syntactic sugar. It's a shorthand for wrapping the symbol in (function foo).
